# remove set of characters surrounding value

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sed, awk

I'm redirecting output of an API call to file

however I always get the following characters surrounding the value I need

```
domainid='^[[39;49;00m^[[33;01m75307d12-e3f4-4a96-ac23-e2a9439f8299^[[39;49;00m'
```

Desired output

```
domainid='75307d12-e3f4-4a96-ac23-e2a9439f8299'
```

I really have no idea how to clean the output and make it look like the above.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the undesired characters by replacing the line with just the submatches you want to keep:

```
... | sed -r "s/(domainid=).*([0-9a-f]{8}(-[0-9a-f]{4}){3}-[0-9a-f]{12}).*/\1'\2'/i"
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are ANSI control characters, or escape sequences, and they typically are used to add colors, underline, and so forth to your output.

First order of business is to check if your API command line tool supports a no-color mode. That would solve your problem at the source.

Barring that, try [this Server Fault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/71285/in-centos-4-4-how-can-i-strip-escape-sequences-from-a-text-file), which has a command to clear ANSI sequences out of a text file using `sed`.